# How should I handle the scroll down operation in the script?

Tags: qtp

In order to capture a bitmap located at the end of the web page, I have to scrolldown the page (if not the code is not capturing the bitmap). How should I handle the scroll down operation in the script?

Answer (score 2):

Are you preforming a bitmap checkpoint on an `IMG` element in the web application? If so then QTP should automatically scroll the object into view. If it doesn't you can try using the undocumented `MakeObjVisible` method.

```
Browser("B").Page("P").Image("I").MakeObjVisible
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that method. Allthough, I experienced that undocumented features are undocumented for a reason: They are instable. I encountered many hangs using the undocumented Highlight method for example.

Comment: @AutomatedChaos, I've never run into hangs during `Highlight` AFAIK it does exactly the same thing as highlighting from the object repository (which obviously *is* documented). Often the reason a feature is undocumented is because it wasn't specified as a feature and was only inserted as the means to another feature (e.g. Highlight from the OR or activating an object before running a step).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the solution of Motti, but if you really, really, really want to perform a scroll down, you can send the type command for the END button to the browser, or just create a Windows Scripting Host object and perform a sendkey "{END}" command.
This should work in that case:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "{END}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set obj = oPage.WebTable("object_Name")
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
obj.ChildItem(2,1,"WebEdit",0).Fireevent "onmouseover"
objWshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
objWshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
```

'This piece of code can be iterated further to find the particular cell you want

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down

```
Set pfr_obj=Browser("p").Page("page")
pfr_obj.RunScript("window.scrollBy(0,900)")
```

Scroll up

```
Set pfr_obj=Browser("p").Page("page")
pfr_obj.RunScript("window.scrollBy(0,-900)")
```

Comment: it working fine very well